# JQuery: how to check if checkbox is checked and add attributes to field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to check whether a check box is checked, and if it is checked, then I want to add the "required" attribute to an adjacent text field.  I've tried it two different ways with no success.  Here are the form elements and my two JQuery attempts.

neither of those will actually trigger the event.  My browser either does nothing at all or triggers an "Empty string passed to getElementById()." event

Form elements:

```
  <div class="col-sm-5">
            <label id="checkboxNumber-label" class="toplabel" for="checkboxNumber">Checkbox</label>
            <g:textField name="checkboxNumber" value="${...checkboxNumber}" class="form-control" required="" aria-labelledby="checkboxNumber-label"/>
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <g:checkBox name="checkboxYesNo" id="checkboxYesNo" value="${...checkboxYesNo}" onclick="chkboxYesChecked()"/> 
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <label id="someTextField-label" class="toplabel" for="someTextField">Some Text Field Here</label>
            <g:textField name="someTextField" id="someTextField" value="${...someTextField}" class="form-control" aria-labelledby="someTextField-label"/>
        </div>
```

JQuery:

```
function chkboxYesChecked(){
        if($('#checkboxYesNo').prop('checked')){
            $('#someTextField').prop('required',true);
            $('#someTextField').append('<span class="required-indicator">*</span>');
        }else{
            $('#someTextField').removeAttr('required');
        }
           }


$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#checkboxYesNo').click(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            $('#someTextField').prop('required',true);
            $('#someTextField').append('<span class="required-indicator">*</span>');
        } else {
            $('#someTextField').removeAttr('required');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Please describe your problem in more depth and try to include an example

Comment: neither of those will actually trigger the event.  My browser either does nothing at all or triggers an "Empty string passed to getElementById()." event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your markup this becomes more convoluted than it needs to be.

```
$(document).on("click", ".checkbox-inline :checkbox", function () {
    var $nextTextbox = $(this).closest("div").next("div").find(":text").first();
    if (this.checked) {
        $nextTextbox.prop("required", true).after('<span class="required-indicator">*</span>');
    } else {
        $nextTextbox.prop("required", false).next('.required-indicator').remove();
    }
});
```

Notes

- This approach uses *event delegation*.
- There are no IDs involved, because I suppose you need the same thing more than once on your page. Tying it to a specific element ID is counter-productive.
- This approach relies on the specific document structure from your sample Grails template. If you want something more flexible and easier-to-read, change your HTML.
- This applies to *all* checkboxes that have a text field in the immediately following `<div>`. Use CSS classes on your elements to filter it/make it apply to specific ones only.
- If there is no immediately following `<div>` with a text box, the function does nothing.
- `$(this).is(":checked")` is superfluous. You don't need jQuery to find out if the current DOM element is checked. `this.checked` is a lot simpler and has the same effect.
- **Don't** use inline event handlers (`onclick="..."`). Ever.

See it in action:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".checkbox-inline :checkbox", function () {
    var $nextTextbox = $(this).closest("div").next("div").find(":text").first();
    if (this.checked) {
        $nextTextbox.prop("required", true).after('<span class="required-indicator">*</span>');
    } else {
        $nextTextbox.prop("required", false).next('.required-indicator').remove();
    }
});
```

```css
input[required] {
    background-color: #FFD1D1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <label id="checkboxNumber-label" class="toplabel" for="checkboxNumber">Checkbox</label>
    <input type="text" name="checkboxNumber" value="${...checkboxNumber}" class="form-control" required="" aria-labelledby="checkboxNumber-label" />
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxYesNo" id="checkboxYesNo" value="${...checkboxYesNo}" />
    </label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <label id="someTextField-label" class="toplabel" for="someTextField">Some Text Field Here</label>
    <input type="text" name="someTextField" id="someTextField" value="${...someTextField}" class="form-control" aria-labelledby="someTextField-label" />
</div>
```

Comment: If I only needed it to hit one checkbox on the page how would I write it then?

Comment: Why would you change it? It works with 1 checkbox and it works with 1000 checkboxes.

Comment: OK I understand.  Could it be possible to implement with a text field that is not adjacent to the checkbox?

Comment: Certainly, but I won't do it. ;-) Here's what I would do. **Hint 1:** Add a `data-required-if="foo"` to any input element on the page that you want to link to the checkbox with ID "foo". Modify the above function: When a checkbox is clicked, it selects *all* input elements on the page, filters them down to those that have their "required-if" equal to the checkbox ID (use jQuery's `.filter()` and `.data()` functions for that). Eventually, the remaining inputs that can easily be made required/not required. **Hint 2:** This is possible without using any explicit loops (no `$.each`, no `for`, etc)

Comment: I just noticed a small difference that I forgot to note.   I'd like the required asterisk * to show up after the text label but before the actual textbox <div>